# JMeter - JSON render in view results tree show invalid JSON

Tags: json, jmeter

I'm using latest JMeter 3.3 testing server APIs,

I'm getting a valid JSON response from server in Text view which looks OK

```
{"code":"1","message":"Template Name not found"}
```

[image]

But when changing to JSON format is shows extra `:` characters

```
{
:   "code":"1",
:   "message":"Template Name not found"
}
```

[image]

In [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) it supposes to show in tree style:

> JSON   The JSON view will show the response in tree style (also handles JSON embedded in JavaScript).

I don't understand why we need such parser and it seems that it's unnecessary for JSON responses, or maybe it seems just a bug in the JMeter UI parser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a [bug](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62545) in JMeter render that was fix and will be available in next version

> change it to a simple four space "tab"